# Cannot simulate my model on LTSpice

Tags: simulation, ltspice, nmos, model

I'm having trouble trying to simulate my NMOS (FDG6301N) on LTSpice. 
I have a permanent error telling me

`x1:ed: unknown circuit node: "nc_01". requested in behavioral source`

I took the model from On semiconductor website.

You can find the model, symbol and part of my schematic [here](http://grosfi.ch/BNEvNIPLKidGM).

The full schematic can be found [here](http://grosfi.ch/0C37mVgJdOsgU).

[image: Part of my schematic]

If you need more data I can post them here.

I'm simulating this NMOS to see its linear behavior. If you know a good NMOS with a huge linear operating range you also can advise me some parts.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: was that model for ltspice or maybe some other spice dialect?

Comment: You didn't connect the 4th pin, so whatever behavioural source that makes use of that voltage cannot use it. Maybe the solution is to simply add a net, unconnected, or with a label.

Comment: On the On Semiconductor website it was written as a PSpice model. Is it then only compatible with Orcad software ?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I added a net, not connected to anything and now the Unknown Circuit node is "n005" and no more "nc_01"

Comment: @RPerun Why not simply post, from the beginning, the whole schematic. Picture might do, for now. The error is telling you that you have a behavioural source which makes use of that node. It was `nc_01` (=not connected), now it's `n005` (=node), so that must be one half of the problem, you have to know where the behavioural source is. Nobody here will be able to guess unless you post everything you have. Help us help you. The model, as it is, should work in LTspice.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I added the link to the full schematic. I also connected a voltage source to this pin and as its name is Vtemp, I supposed it simulates the temperature (25 V = 25 °C ) Is it a good supposition ?  Since I've done it, the simulation runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, internally, the model has an E-source in the `*TEMP` section:

`ED 101 0 VALUE {V(50,100)}`

which is connected to the `TEMP` pin, and whose expression is, after using the expanded listing:

`b:x1:§eout x1:4x x1:6x v=v(x1:1x)*v(x1:3x)`

so it multiplies an internal voltage to the external one. That is supplied at the `TEMP` pin, and comes, most probably, from some thermal design model (heatsink, or similar). If you don't use temperature, then simply ground that pin, else you can supply the temperaure (probably in <sup>o</sup>C, as Volts, e.g. 58<sup>o</sup>C = 58V).

Comment: Thank you very much dear concerned Citizen :) As I said in the question I'm looking for a good linear NMOS to control tension on the O_MOS node, if you know one can you advise it to me ? If no, anyway, you helped me find a solution to my main problem.

Comment: @RPerun You might want to look into JFETs, though they come with their own drawbacks. However, this is another question.